Custom table grouped by column Filament
I have a <table_name> with ±100k rows and I want to display only grouped rows based on <column_name> with Filament inside a Laravel project.
So on that table I will have columns like: <column_group_name>, Load Time (that will be the diff between first and last created_at) and more.
I tried multiple things based on Filament documentation.

Table Builder->Grouping rows
Table Builder->Adding a table to a Livewire component

A few examples of code that I've tried:
return $table
    ->query(fn () => MODEL::query())
    ->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->select('<column_name>')->groupBy('<column_name>');
    })
    ->columns([
        TextColumn::make('<column_name>')
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable()
    ]);

return $table
    ->columns([
        TextColumn::make('<column_name>')
            ->summarize(Sum::make()),
    ])
    ->defaultGroup('<column_name>')
    ->groupsOnly(); // On this one I get timed-out

Another result was to get them grouped, but instead of getting the numbers of grouped rows I'm getting in the table all ±100k rows.
As for a new Livewire component I'm not sure how to get the data from the Livewire component instead of the main Resource.
